# Generating a new Excel while retaining old formula from template Excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-formula

I have an Excel template with first 5 columns left blank (to be populated from an XML). The sixth column has a drop-down list such that depending on whatever value is selected from the list, a value appears in 7th column. This is done by using INDEX-MATCH formula for the 7th column.

```
=INDEX(Sheet7!$B$1:$B$312,MATCH(F3,Sheet7!$A$1:$A$312,0))
```

The task is to take this template Excel, and using POI, populate the first 5 columns and generate a new Excel workbook. (Not changing in the existing sheet).

The problem is when I generate the new Excel workbook, the formula isn't copied over from the template. It is really important to retain the formula for the task I am working on. I read about

```
formulaEvaluator()
```

but I don't think it'll work in that case because I need the formula to be retained as it is. I cannot evaluate it before copying as there won't be any data in column 6 at that point to evaluate the formula and store the value.

I'd really appreciate if someone who has any experience in this area could guide me a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the `Cell`, simply call:

```
String formula = cell.getCellFormula();
```

Note though that this will only work if the cell is formula cell.  IE: `cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA`.  If the cell is not a formula cell, you're going to end up with an `IllegalStateException` as described in the [API](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellFormula%28%29)

Comment: @akoksis I'll try to see if I can make it work the way your suggested. Right now the way it works, it just takes whatever text is in the file, adds the first 5 columns. I didn't have to use any formula until recently so it was working fine. It just won't copy over the formula. Thanks for your response.